# How to download a PDF from S3 in Lambda using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I created a React application using AWS Amplify, and part of the functionality that I need to implement is a a post-processing lambda function that happens after a user has made a purchase on the site.

The function needs to (1) retrieve a PDF file from S3, (2) alter the file in a few ways, and then (3) upload the file back to S3 under a new name. I am getting stuck in that first part when it comes to downloading the file as a blob in Lambda.

I followed the documentation in [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js/#file-access-levels) that suggested the following code:

```
import { Storage } from "@aws-amplify/storage"

await Storage.get('test.txt', { 
    level: 'public'
});
```

I realized that the function that AWS created uses ES5 and not ES6, and I cannot import packages that way. I need to use `const something = require('something');` instead.

I tried following the documentation that I listed above, but I can't seem to find a good path forward. Is Lambda not supposed to be able to run a quick pipeline and retrieve a file from S3?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AWS SDK for Node to retrieve the object from S3 and post the update. Amplify modules are targeted for browser use. You function will also require an execution role that permits the function to `getObject` and `putObject` in the appropriate S3 bucket.

For Node.js, I would recommend using v3 of the AWS SDK. Specifically, look at the `GetObjectCommand`.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjectcommand.html